# How to print out even-numbered indexes for arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm supposed to write a program using for loops that print out the even indexes of my array. For example, if I create an array that has 10 numbers, it will have indexes from 0-9 so in that case I would print out the numbers at index 2, 4, 6 and 8. This is what I wrote so far but it doesn't work. Please note that I am not trying to print out the even numbers of the array. All I want are the even indexes.

Example I enter the following array: `3,7,5,5,5,7,7,9,9,3`

Program output:

```
5 // (the number at index 2)
5 // (the number at index 4)
7 // (the number at index 6)
9 // (the number at index 8)
```

My Code:

```
public class Arrayevenindex 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number; // variable that will represent how many elements the user wants the array to have

        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" How many elements would you like your array to have");
        number = key.nextInt();
        int [] array = new int [number];

        // let the user enter the values of the array.  
        for (int index = 0; index < number; index ++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" Value" + (index+1) + " :");
            array[index] = key.nextInt();
        }
        // Print out the even indexes 
        System.out.println("/nI am now going to print out the even indexes");
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index ++) 
        {
            if (array[number+1]%2==0)
                System.out.print(array[number]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ( array[number+1]%2==0)` -> don't you want to be checking `index` instead?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how it's "not working"? Have you tried stepping through in a debugger and looking for the problem there? It becomes fairly apparent that you are testing the wrong value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just change your for loop and get rid of the inner IF...

```
for( int index = 0; index < array.length; index += 2) {
    System.out.println(array[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just absolutely same thing using java 8 `Stream` API

```
 Integer[] ints = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 IntStream.range(0, ints.length).filter(i ->  i % 2 == 0).forEach(i -> System.out.println(ints[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this would be sufficient

```
// For loop to search array
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  // If to validate that the index is divisible by 2
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
  System.out.print(array[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it works:also I am not printing out index[0] because technically its not even thats why I started the for loop at 2. Your post did help me a lot. I also thank everyone else as well that took the time to post an answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Arrayevenindex 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number;  // variable that will represent how many elements the user wants the array to have


    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" How many elements would you like your array to have");
    number = key.nextInt();
    int [] array = new int [number];


// let the user enter the values of the array.  
for ( int index = 0; index < number; index ++) 
{
 System.out.print(" Value" + (index+1) + " :");
 array[index] = key.nextInt();



}
// Print out the even indexes 
System.out.println("/nI am now going to print out the even indexes");
for ( int index = 2; index < array.length; index +=2) 
{

    System.out.print(array[index] + " ");



}

    }
```

}